# Internet Explorer ignores Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've recently been trying to include a Lightbox-Clone called "EnlargeIt" into my website. Everything works fine in every Browser except, big surprise, Intenret Explorer.
Let me quote directly from the manual:

> Integrate your thumbnails like this into the of your web page:

```
<a href=”images/fullsize_file.jpg” target=”_blank” onclick=”return false;”><img 
src="images/thumb_file.jpg" alt="My first picture" onclick="enlarge(this);" 
longdesc="images/fullsize_file.jpg" /></a>
```

> The attribute longdescis used for the qualified filename of the full
>   size image, meaning that if  the file is in a different folder, the
>   correct pathmust be included (in the example, it’s images/).  The
>   attribute altis used for the picture caption. If you don’t define it
>   or leave it empty, no  caption (title bar text) will be displayed for
>   thispicture.  Around the image, there’s an …element linking to
>   the full size image in a new  window (target=”_blank”). It’s very
>   important, that you set the attribute onclick=”return  false;”. This
>   way, the link won’t be used if Javascript is available.

I've done exactly as said in this manual and it works fine until you try it with IE9. You click on it and it does...nothing at all.
Every other Browser handles it correctly, even older versions of IE.
It does show the link while hovering over it but I guess the "return false" prevents the default action?

My Code:

```
<a href="fileadmin/templates/HTML/main.html" target="_blank" onclick="return false;"/><img src="fileadmin/templates/images/logo_subline_moreInformation.jpg" style="width: 520px; height: 130px; cursor:pointer;border:none;border-width:0px;text-decoration:none;" alt="Alt" id="Image"
  onclick="enlarge(this);" longdesc="ifr::fileadmin/templates/HTML/main.html::800::600"/></a><br>
```

Thank you!

Oh and have a nice day!

Comment: What's the code for `enlarge` function?

Comment: You can see the whole code here : http://enlargeit.timos-welt.de/english/11/building_blocks.php

Answer (score 0):

With a little googling... Doctype issue?
http://enlargeit.timos-welt.de/forum/viewtopic.php?p=471&sid=4540aa596fcc5870fe02618e27d374dc

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have seen and tried the solutions from this spam-infested forum. Sadly neither of the two worked. I also imagined that it might rather be a syntax issue than one with enlargeit itself?

Comment: Syntax looks okay, as you say, it works everywhere but IE9.  Cannot really help other than make a few suggestions... make sure your id="Image" is unique on your page; use HTML5 if you can; try to remove the onclick="return false;" (maybe it is preventing the event on IE9).

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. "Image" is unique, I use HTML5. Removing the "return false" makes it work on IE9, but FF, Opera, Chrome will then call the function AND open in new Tab

Comment: Do you happen to know an alternative to EnlargeIt?

Comment: Interesting that removing "return false" worked for IE9.  Try this: onclick="function(event) { enlarge(this); event = event || window.event; if (event.stopPropagation){event.stopPropagation();} else event.cancelBubble = true; }".

It stops the event from bubbling.  So, in theory, the img onclick will stop the event from bubbling to the link.  source: http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing.

Comment: Interesting Code. All Browsers react the same to it: Opening in a new Tab. Which of the onclick properties would I swap with the provided code? I tried every combination. It either did nothing or both will open in tabs.

Comment: Swap this one onclick="enlarge(this);", remove the return false.

Comment: All Browsers will open it in a new tab. Very interesting I must say.

Comment: It looks like the event is still bubbling up.  I had a look at their examples.  Remove the link. Change to a div instead:
<div><img src="..." /></div>

Comment: changed to <div><img src="fileadmin/templates/images/logo_subline_moreInformation.jpg" style="width: 520px; height: 130px; cursor:pointer;border:none;border-width:0px;text-decoration:none;" alt="Alt" id="Image"
  onclick="function(event) { enlarge(this); event = event || window.event; if (event.stopPropagation){event.stopPropagation();} else event.cancelBubble = true; }" longdesc="ifr::fileadmin/templates/HTML/main.html::800::600"/></div> Now it doesnt do anything, is not recognized as a link

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18178/discussion-between-blazes-and-halest)